# scp through intermediate server

Tags: ssh, scp, ssh-tunnel

I need to copy a file from a computer I can only access via SSHing into an intermediate computer.

```
Home -> server.com -> cluster.com
```

I'm trying to copy from cluster.com to home. I can ssh from home but not to home.
The connection

```
server.com-> cluster.com
```

has an RSA public key but server will not allow

`Home -> server RSA public key`.

I've tried

```
home$ ssh server.com -L 2000:final:22 -N
```

which gave

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
```

I've also tried

```
ssh -fN -L 4567:cluster.com:22 server.com
```

then

```
ssh cluster.com -L 2000:final:22 -N
```

which resulted in.

```
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I got these ideas from 
[scp files via intermediate host](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host)
and
[Must I sftp to an intermediate server?](https://superuser.com/questions/262926/must-i-sftp-to-an-intermediate-server)

but can't seem to get the results to work, some of the other examples in the first link I can't follow so have only tried the ones I can. I never seem to be able to get ssh to do what I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSH server on `server.com` is configured to refuse all TCP forwarding attempts through it; using `-L` will not work.

---

An alternative to SFTP and SCP is good old `tar`:

```
ssh server.com "ssh cluster.com \"cd mydir && tar cz myfile\"" | tar xvz
```

Or `cat`:

```
ssh server.com "ssh cluster.com \"cat mydir/myfile\"" | pv > myfile
```

The "`| pv`" part is optional; it causes a nice progress bar to be displayed if you have the *pv* program installed.

Comment: Thanks, all.txt is a test file, the file I ultimately want to copy is a large (5 gig) tar.bzip file dose that matter that its already tared up?

Comment: @Tommy: For a single file? See update. Or just remove the `z` option from both ends.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by adding a "-t" option:
ssh -t server.com "ssh cluster.com \"cat mydir/myfile\""

Since I have a .pem key i use to connect to server.com, and a password to connect to cluster.com, i had to insert another -i before the -t to point to the .pem file.