# sftp connection from one server to another server

Tags: ssh, cmd.exe, sftp

I want to connect to a sftp server from another sftp server.How do i do that.After i connect to a sftp server,at the sftp prompt i would need to connect to another sftp server.How can that be done and is it possible that way.I am doing it in command prompt.

I connected to one sftp server.After successfully connecting to the server and from the sftp prompt,i tried connecting to another sftp server but it gave invalid command.I also tried using ssh but that also didn't work out,giving the same error as sftp command.

Comment: No not really as i wouldn't like to go for a tool like winscp or something similar due to certain restrictions and constraints but would rather do everything using command prompt.

Comment: The suggested tool is ssh, which does hops.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/a/262940/213663